# Caesar cipher Encryption

Tags: python, encryption

I need to write an encrypted text of the words python, hacker, and wow and has a distance of 3 using a Caesar cipher in Python that does not include the use of raw_input. This is what I have so far but I keep getting an error message and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
>>> plainText = input("python: ") 
python: distance = int(input("3: ")) 
>>> code = "" 
>>> for ch in plainText:    
        ordValue = ord(ch)  
        cipherValue = ordValue + distance   
        if cipherValue > ord('z'):      
        cipherValue = ord('a') = distance - \                 
        (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)        
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: What do you want `cipherValue = ord('a') = distance - (ord('z') - ordValue + ')` to *mean*? Because that's where the error is.

Comment: I'm really not sure to be honest, I was following the example in the book

Comment: If that's the literal code in the book you have a badly edited book.

Comment: I figured that... So how do I fix this?

Comment: That line appears to want to apply a modulus operation; anything that went beyond `z` should be added to `ord('a')` instead. `cipherValue = ord('a') + (cipherValue - ord('z'))` would make more sense.

Comment: >>> plainText = input("python: ")
python: distance = int(input("3: ")
>>> code = ""
>>> for ch in plainText:
 ordValue = ord(ch)
 cipherValue = ordValue + distance
 if cipherValue > ord('z'):
  cipherValue = ord('a') + (cipherValue - ord('z'))
  code += chr(cipherValue)
  print(code)

  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 3, in <module>
    cipherValue = ordValue + distance
NameError: name 'distance' is not defined

Comment: Right, you copied your code straight into the interpreter, which first executes the `plainText = input("python: ") ` line. This line asks for user input, and because you are pasting the `distance = int(input("3: ")) ` is read as that user input.

Comment: In other words, that line wasn't executed as Python code; it is stored in the `plainText` variable instead.

Comment: so I need to retype the whole code to straighten it out then

Comment: Don't copy-paste this into the interpreter, but run it as a file instead.

Comment: I just retyped the whole thing in Python in Idle and it still did not work

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be entering this code into an interactive prompt, rather than saving it as a file and running it. If this is the case, then when you use `input`, the window will prompt you for input before allowing you to continue entering code.

```
plainText = input("python: ")
```

After you enter this line, type the word you wish to encrypt and press enter. Only then should you write this line:

```
distance = int(input("3: "))
```

And you should enter the distance you want before starting on the next line, `code = ""`.

As a stylistic tip, I suggest changing the prompt texts from `"python:"` and `"3:"` to something like "text to encrypt: " and "distance: ", so it is apparent to the user what he's supposed to enter.

---

Next, you have an indentation error here:

```
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):      
    cipherValue = ord('a') = distance - \
```

the lines after an `if` condition should be indented one level farther in.

```
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):      
        cipherValue = ord('a') = distance - \
```

---

Next, you have two problems on these lines.

```
    cipherValue = ord('a') = distance - \
    (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
```

- You should not have any spaces after the line continuation character `\`. In any case, it may be better to just write the entire expression on one line, since the line isn't really long enough to warrant breaking up into two lines.
- The second equals sign is a typo. It should be a plus sign.

-

```
    cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
```

---

At this point, your program should run without any errors, but it doesn't yet produce any output. As you encipher each character, add it to `code`. Then print it after the loop ends.

```
plainText = input("text to encrypt: ") 
distance = int(input("distance: ")) 
code = "" 
for ch in plainText:    
    ordValue = ord(ch)  
    cipherValue = ordValue + distance   
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):      
        cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
    code = code + chr(cipherValue)
print(code)
#to do: write this to a file, or whatever else you want to do with it
```

Here, `chr` converts the numeric `cipherValue` into its equivalent letter.

---

Result:

```
text to encrypt: hacker
distance: 13
unpxre
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the second assignment '=' in the last line of the `for` loop.  It must be a addition '+' sign.

Try this:

```
plainText = input("Enter text to encrypt: ")
distance = int(input("Enter number of offset: "))
code = ""
for ch in plainText:
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordValue + distance
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):
        cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - \
            (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
    code = code + chr(cipherValue)
print(code)
```

Answer (score -1):

you just need to change the ordValue from +1 to +2